# Log4j Warnings on the console

Tags: java, log4j

I have a java application which is using log4j. I placed the log4j.xml file in the source folder. At runtime, the log4j is creating the files(trace, error) on the given location but not able to print the log messages and I see the warnings on the console. I searched for solutions all over and I am unable to resolve it. I tried with the BasicConfigurator.configure() in the main method, it worked and printed the log messages on the console but i want to print them on the files.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.aafes.pix.Pix).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for 
more info.


Screenshot(01) of the location where I placed my log4j.xml file in the project.
Screenshot(02) of the files that were created on the location.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCbpP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq7dW.png)

BELOW IS MY LOG4J.XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>

<appender name="mapps_all" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/home/tlog/logs/mapps.all.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{ipAddress} - %X{messageId}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="mapps_trace" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/home/tlog/logs/mapps.trace.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="trace"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{ipAddress} - %X{messageId}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="mapps_error" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/home/tlog/logs/mapps.error.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{ipAddress} - %X{messageId}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="WARN"/> 
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/> 
    </filter>     
</appender>

<appender name="mapps_local" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/home/tlog/logs/mapps.local.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="LOCAL"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{ipAddress} - %X{messageId}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG"/> 
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/> 
    </filter>     
</appender>
<appender name="mapps_debug" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/home/tlog/logs/mapps.debug.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{ipAddress} - %X{messageId}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="DEBUG"/> 
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
    </filter>     
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>  
</appender>

<appender name="mapps_info" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/home/tlog/logs/mapps.info.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{ipAddress} - %X{messageId}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="INFO"/> 
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
    </filter>     
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>  
</appender>

<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="com.aafes.demand">
  <level value ="all"/>
  <appender-ref ref="mapps_trace"/>
  <appender-ref ref="mapps_debug"/>
  <appender-ref ref="mapps_info"/>
  <appender-ref ref="mapps_error"/>
  <appender-ref ref="mapps_all"/>
</logger>


<logger name="org.apache.axis">
   <level value="info"/>
   <appender-ref ref="mapps_trace"/>
</logger>

<root>
  <priority value="all"></priority>
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Below is the main method:

```
package com.aafes.pix;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.*;

import org.xml.sax.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.sql.Connection;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class Pix {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Pix.class
            .getName());


     // all the reset stuff

}
```

Comment: You need to provide log4j.xml also as well as a class where you're using logger. And it's better to add it as code here instead of any images.

Comment: hI john, please see my updated post with xml file

Comment: can you verify if the files mapps.log are created ?

Comment: @ElarbiMohamedAymen yes i see them created with log messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update `root`. Add some appender there.

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</root>
```

I guess as there is no appender provided for `root` and no separate logger named `com.aafes.pix`, so log4j signals about that.

Or you could create a separate logger:

```
<logger name="com.aafes.pix">
   <level value="info"/>
   <appender-ref ref="mapps_trace"/>
</logger>
```

And please pay attention that those are just examples - so you should use appender you need instead `mapps_trace` here `<appender-ref ref="mapps_trace"/>` !

I would leave `root` to print to the console, but only DEBUG stuff or so.

Comment: Thanks john, but when i updated the root, it is printing the messages on the console

Comment: @sai add something you need instead of <appender-ref ref="stdout" /> . stdout in your case prints to the console.

Comment: Hey @john, thanks a lot. I just updated the logger name and my issue is resolved. Thanks for saving my time.